# Do table hints apply to all tables or only the preceding table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have

```
select * from tableA, tableB with (nolock)
```

does the nolock hint apply to tableB, or does it apply to both tables? Do I need to do

```
select * from tableA with (nolock), tableB with (nolock)
```

for the hint to apply to both tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table hints only apply to the preceeding table. You need to do

```
select * from tableA with (nolock), tableB with (nolock)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Table Hints only apply to the preceding table. To set this for all tables in the query you could do.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

`NOLOCK` / `READ UNCOMMITTED` can cause inconsistent results however. Have you considered [RCSI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404.aspx) instead?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to RCSI; I had not come across it before and it is a option for us, but it would need extensive testing.